# Can't import Eclipse Datatools

Tags: java, eclipse, sql-data-tools

I am just trying to import the datatools of eclipse after I installed the necessary plugins for the DTP (DTP, GEF and EMF + XSD). 
Eclipse keeps on telling me, that the import cannot be found. 
Actually, I am not even able to import ANYTHING from org.eclipse.***

Help appreciated!!

```
import org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.sql.query.ValueExpressionColumn;
import org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.sql.query.helper.StatementHelper;
import org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.SQLParseErrorInfo;
import org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.SQLParserException;
```

Comment: Is this a plugin you are writing? You can only access these things from Eclipse plugins.

Comment: It's a plugin I installed and am not able to access right now
The related filed have been installed into eclipse/features

Comment: Yes, but are **you** writing an Eclipse plugin or just a normal Java program?

Comment: no no just a normal java program

Comment: You can't use Eclipse plugins in a normal Java program.